# Cant see databases of mysql from command prompt in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, database

1) I have installed mysql server and mysql client through `apt-get install mysql-server` and `apt-get install mysql-client`

2) when I run sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql, I see following:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      15138/mysqld
```

I think it is running

3) now I go to usr/share/mysql and type:
`show databases;` it shows me following,

```
The program 'show' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install nmh
```

Can anybody please tell me what is the problem ? Am I running command from wrong directory ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to login to your mysql account by this command:

```
mysql -u <username> -p
```

`<username>` should be replaced by your username. Then it will ask you for your password. Enter you password and run this command :

```
show databases;
```

It will be better if you also install :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-common
```

Comment: welcome! the thing you tried before would just show the active connections! Its no where related to the databases that you have. And to enter mysql commands, you have to always login. Otherwise it is not possible to do anything in mysql!

Comment: Duplicate answers adding little information are generally frowned-upon bu the community.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS I explained the commands (step by step) rather than just giving what to do.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS - could you post the dup link , it would be better to edit this answer and post the source link :)

Comment: IMO the other answer has a bit more explanation.

Comment: @tijybba The duplicate is to an older answer to this very question.

Comment: The note about installing mysql-common being "better" is a little subjective.  Why is it better?  What exactly, will mysql-common do for this user?

Comment: @PranitBauva There shouldn't be a space between `-u` and `<username>`. I have tested on my machine. It works intermittently with the space; all the time without the space.

Comment: i always insert a space between them.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you're trying to enter SQL commands from the Ubuntu command line.  You need to enter them from the MySQL command line:

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u user -p password

mysql> show databases;
```